# Can't find kubeadm token after initializing master

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

When i run `kubeadm init` it shows a token that I should use from the other hosts to connect to this host.  Where is that token stored?  I'm trying to figure out more ways to automate this by adding kubeadm inside of Terraform.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you can generate token and use it for init command.  'kubeadm token generate' then use '/usr/bin/kubeadm init --token <value>'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **--token**
>
> By default, **kubeadm init** automatically generates the token used to
>   initialise each new node. If you would like to manually specify this
>   token, you can use the --token flag. The token must be of the format
>   ‘<6 character string>.<16 character string>’.

you can see token value on master node using command:

```
cat /etc/kubernetes/pki/tokens.csv
```

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, just after I posted this I re-read the guide and this time noticed the `--token` flag.  That will work for this solution.  I though I had checked that `tokens.csv` file but upon re-inspection you are right!  Thank you!

Comment: Can't verify that. The files contains a string, but nothing there is in token format.

Comment: Show master token: 'kubeadm token list'

Comment: there isnt such a file

Answer (score 62):

The instruction for Kubernetes 1.9.x (and above) can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-token/#cmd-token-create).

The commands I used are:

```
kubeadm token generate
kubeadm token create <generated-token> --print-join-command --ttl=0
```

Comment: Note that it's safer to set TTL (or omit the -ttl flag to set default 24h TTL).

Comment: after k8s 1.25, the output of "kubeadm token create <generated-token> --print-join-command --ttl=0" is not enough.

you also need to specify "--cri-socket [socket]".

see https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/

Answer (score 24):

Run this command in the master node to get the token

```
kubeadm token list
```

Answer (score 4):

```
kubectl -n kube-system get secret clusterinfo -o yaml | grep token-map | awk '{print $2}' | base64 -d | sed "s|{||g;s|}||g;s|:|.|g;s/\"//g;" | xargs echo
```

Comment: This should be the solution. But instead of the sed block I'd write `awk -F\" '{print $2 "." $4}'`because it's a little more readable.

Comment: what is clusterinfo. how can i find that, because i am seeing an error that says "secrets" clusterinfo is not found.

Comment: same here v1.8.5 - no clusterinfo secret

Comment: `sudo kubeadm token list | awk 'NR == 2 {print $1}'`

Answer (score 3):

Try to create new as per below command as initial token is valid only 24 hours.

```
kubeadm token create  --ttl=0
```

Here ttl=0 means, generated token will never expire.

Then join node as per below command:

```
kubeadm join <generated_token>
```

If you get any error for verifying ca hash, then join as per below:

```
kubeadm join <generated_token> --discovery-token-unsafe-skip-ca-verification
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way to avoid creating new token is -

1. `kubeadm token list`
2. `kubeadm token create <copied token from previous command output>** --print-join-command`

you will get JOIN command to run on any physical/vitual machine to join kubernetes cluster....

Comment: False. This will error with "a token with id 'xxxx' already exists"

Answer (score -2):

Use this command : `$ sudo kubeadm token list`

Still, if you did not get, use following commands

```
$ sudo kubeadm reset
$ sudo kubeadm init
```

Comment: No... If you don't see any available token, maybe it's timed out. Create another one, not resetting the whole cluster. 

Create token with `kubeadm token create --print-join-command`.

Comment: Seriously - I cannot believe "reset if it does not work" is even an answer.